# How can I work around frozen cursor bug (Ubuntu 16.10 on Intel i5-7200u)

Tags: intel-graphics, 16.10

I have a 1-month old Acer Aspire F5-573-58VX that came with Win-10 installed. It relies on its Intel i5-7200u for its graphics.

I succeeded in dual-booting Ubuntu 16.04 with EFI and secure-boot both enabled, but was suffering random freezes at 3-30 minutes of use, even after setting the c-state limit in grub. It hangs both with and without Intel microcode. So I upgraded to 16.10 hoping that a newer kernel would have a fix in it.

It's still freezing at random (many apps, and sometimes using only the desktop controls). It still has the c-state parameter in grub.

It appears that if I leave the system untouched with the cursor in an empty area, then no freeze will occur (I can see display changing) as long as I don't touch anything. Bittorrent runs reliably overnight, and then the machine freezes within seconds of my moving the cursor to a control in the morning.

Thunderbird is also suspicious: I can work most of an hour OK as long as I never move the cursor over the scroll slider in the folder pane. However, bringing the cursor close enough to change the slider's appearance will usually freeze the machine.

My faint suspicion is that there's a race condition related to hovering (and highlighting controls under the cursor) that might deadlock the UI at a low level.

When frozen, soft restart and reboot (ctrl-alt-back & ctrl-alt-del) both fail. Only a forced power-off has any effect.

Synaptic says I have an intel driver update utility installed, but I don't know if it has run. When I try to sudo it, I am told that the command is not found. I have been unable to locate it in the file system. If anyone knows where that goes (or where to hunt), that might be helpful.

I do not know how to ssh into it (yet) to get a dmesg report, but I have a crossover cable and an old laptop (Ubuntu 10.04) with which to try if necessary. I'd need a lesson in telling it to allow the intrusion.

I've thought about filing a bug, but I can't get the requisite debugging info, and there are already a bunch of Intel CPU/GPU bug reports anyway (though they can't get at dmesg either). I figure I'll have to work-around the issue (and mostly use Win-10) until there's a patch for it.

Comment: Addendum: I found the logs. There's one error: "drm:parse_csr_fw [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* Unknown stepping info, firmware loading failed"

Comment: Based on additional reading, it appears that this is fixed in kernel 4.6+. My incremental upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 had not given me a newer kernel; the kernel was unchanged at 4.4, and the problem persisted. A fresh install and reformat from an Ubuntu 16.10 optical disk finally gave me kernel 4.8. The stepping-info error went away, and the machine has been stable for days.